# Adding new php library into Magento2

Tags: magento2

Please help me to find a way to add new php library to Magneto2. In Magetno1 I add it to lib folder and then I could use it in my custom modules... But in Magento2 I am trying to do the same but no go... Anybody already try to do that or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way would be to install it via composer.

depends on the library. It has to have a composer.json with autoloading settings defined.

if the library has a valid composer.json you can install it with the following command in your magento2 root:

composer require vendor/name:version

with vendor/name = the name that is defined in the composer.json

Comment: Here is the trick lib doesn't have valid composer.json... But I can make it no problem... I thought that I can just copy it to lib/internal folder an do some magic in main composer.json file to do mapping like for Magento/Framework or something like that ... Thanks for the answer I will try to do that.

Comment: magento itself does only autoload its own framework from the lib/internal directory: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/composer.json#L219. So the library has to take care of the autoloading itself and then, with a valid composer.json autoloading, can easily be installed in the vendor dir

Comment: Hey man, just want to say thank you... Lot of issues were here for this lib... using it on php7 don't work... And you were right about composer, just I needed to add custom autoloader. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: @DavidVerholen I have use Third party Libs (DOMPDF) and setup it like lib/internal and call to my helper but getting error to Source class *** generation does not exist . Means Libs file's internal class is not create into generation so getting error. Please let me know proper solution.

Comment: For future readers.. In magento 2.2 adding library code to lib/internal doesn't work: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10985